# Unpacking iterable into other iterable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

While reading data from a ASCII file, I find myself doing something like this:

```
(a, b, c1, c2, c3, d, e, f1, f2) = (float(x) for x in line.strip().split())
c = (c1, c2, c3)
f = (f1, f2)
```

If I have a determinate number of elements per line (which I do)¹ and only one multi-element entry to unpack, I can use something like `(a, b, *c, d, e) = ...' ([Extended iterable unpacking](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)).

Even if I don't, I can of course replace *one* of the two multi-element entries from the example above by a starred component: `(a, b, *c, d, e, f1, f2) = ...`.

As far as I can tell, the `itertools` are not of immediate use here.

Are there any alternatives to the three-line code above that may be considered "more pythonic" for a reason I'm probably not aware of?

<sup>¹It's determinate but still varies per line, the pattern is too complicated for `numpy`s functions `loadtxt` or `genfromtxt`.</sup>

Comment: Added python-3.0x tag because pep3132 (Extented iterable unpacking) is implemented on python 3.0 and higher.

Answer (score 1):

If you use such statements really often, and want maximum flexibility and reusability of code instead of writing such patterns really often, I'd propose creating a small function for it. Just put it into some module and import it (you can even import the script I created).

For usage examples, see the `if __name__=="__main__"` block. The trick is to use a list of group ids to group values of `t` together. The length of this id list should be at least the same as the length of `t`.

I will only explain the main concepts, if you don't understand anything, just ask.

I use `groupby` from itertools. Even though it might not be straightforward how to use it here, I hope it might be understandable soon.

As `key`-function I use a method I dynamically create via a factory-function. The main concept here is "closures". The list of group ids is being "attached" to the internal function `get_group`. Thus:

- The list is specific to each call to `extract_groups_from_iterable`. You can use it multiple times, no globals are used
- The state of this list is shared between subsequent calls to the same instance of `get_group` (remember: functions are objects, too! So I have two instances of `get_group` during the execution of my script.

Beside of this, I have a simple method to create either lists or scalars from the groups returned by `groupby`.

That's it.

```
from itertools import groupby

def extract_groups_from_iterable(iterable, group_ids):
    return [_make_list_or_scalar(g) for k, g in 
                        groupby(iterable, _get_group_id_provider(group_ids))
           ]

def _get_group_id_provider(group_ids):
    def get_group(value, group_ids = group_ids):
        return group_ids.pop(0)
    return get_group

def _make_list_or_scalar(iterable):
    list_ = list(iterable)
    return list_ if len(list_) != 1 else list_[0]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = range(9)
    group_ids1 = [1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8]
    a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h = extract_groups_from_iterable(t1, group_ids1)

    for varname in "abcdefgh":
        print varname, globals()[varname]

    print

    t2 = range(15)
    group_ids2 = [1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,8]
    a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h = extract_groups_from_iterable(t2, group_ids2)

    for varname in "abcdefgh":
        print varname, globals()[varname]
```

Output is:

```
a 0
b 1
c 2
d 3
e [4, 5]
f 6
g 7
h 8

a 0
b [1, 2]
c 3
d 4
e [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
f [10, 11, 12]
g 13
h 14
```

Once again, this might seem like overkill, but if this helps you reducing your code, use it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just slice a tuple?

```
t = tuple(float(x) for x in line.split())
c = t[2:5]  #maybe t[2:-4] instead?
f = t[-2:]
```

demo:

```
>>> line = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
>>> t = tuple(float(x) for x in line.split())
>>> c = t[2:5]  #maybe t[2:-4] instead?
>>> f = t[-2:]
>>> c
(3.0, 4.0, 5.0)
>>> t
(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0)
>>> c = t[2:-4]
>>> c
(3.0, 4.0, 5.0)
```

While we're on the topic of being pythonic, `line.strip().split()` can always be safely written as `line.split()` where `line` is a string.  `split` will strip the whitespace for you when you don't give it any arguments.

Comment: In reality, I have 7 distinct elemets, so I would need to do `a, b, c, d = t[:4]; e = t[4:6]; f, g, h = t[6:9]`... not sure if that's an improvement. Perhaps it is.